# CV2 Draw ellipse only on masked area

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to make a circle under the player on soccer field, similar to this:

[image]

If I just do a circle around the player's feet, it looks bad:

[image]

I'm trying to draw the circle only on the green part of the field (to make it more 3D).

First I masked only the green part on the field, using the following code:

```
def mask(img):
    ## convert to hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
    lower = (36, 25, 25)
    upper = (86, 255, 255)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    ## slice the green
    imask = mask == 0
    green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
    green[imask] = img[imask]
    img = green
    return img
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

How can I draw the ellipse only on the green (after the masking - black) part?

**P.S. This is the full code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def mask(img):
    ## convert to hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
    lower = (36, 25, 25)
    upper = (86, 255, 255)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    ## slice the green
    imask = mask == 0
    green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
    # green.fill(255)
    green[imask] = img[imask]
    img = green
    return img


def player_ellipse(img, player_point):
    axesLength = (45, 20)
    angle = 0
    startAngle = 0
    endAngle = 360
    # Red color in BGR
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    # Line thickness of 5 px
    thickness = 5
    img = cv2.ellipse(img, player_point, axesLength, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color, thickness)
    return img


def main():
    img = cv2.imread('img.png')
    point = (160, 665)

    img = player_ellipse(img, point)
    img = mask(img)

    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


main()
```

And this is player without any editing:
[image: cccccccc]

Comment: Draw the full ellipse to a copy of the image and then copy to your wanted mage according to the mask (not imask). In c++ it would be mat.copyTo(img, mask) but not sure about python/numpy

Comment: in python you'd use numpy, use a boolean (mask) array as the "index". `target[mask] = source[mask]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. All that lefts to do is to copy the pixels from the original image (without ellipse) using the founded mask as answered by [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka) and [Christoph Rackwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602877/christoph-rackwitz) in comments.

Optionally you may apply some morphological operations to make the mask more appealing.

So the steps are:

1. Draw an ellipse:
   [image]
2. Extract a mask using green color:
   [image]
3. [Optional] Apply mask erode:
   [image]
4. Copy pixels from original image using the mask:

`img_with_ellipse[green_mask] = img[green_mask]`

[image]

Complete example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def mask(img):
    ## convert to hsv
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
    lower = (36, 25, 25)
    upper = (86, 255, 255)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=5) == 0
    return mask


def player_ellipse(img, player_point):
    axesLength = (45, 20)
    angle = 0
    startAngle = 0
    endAngle = 360
    # Red color in BGR
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    # Line thickness of 5 px
    thickness = 5
    img = cv2.ellipse(
        img.copy(),
        player_point,
        axesLength,
        angle,
        startAngle,
        endAngle,
        color,
        thickness,
    )
    return img


def main():
    img = cv2.imread("img.png")
    point = (160, 665)

    green_mask = mask(img)

    img_with_ellipse = player_ellipse(img, point)
    img_with_ellipse[green_mask] = img[green_mask]

    cv2.imshow("img", img_with_ellipse)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


main()
```